# E: Package 'libssl1.0.0' has no installation candidate

Tags: software-installation

I get this error message when I try to install libssl1.0.0'.

How can I solve it? I use Ubuntu 19.04

Comment: The package `libssl1.0.0` was dropped from Ubuntu after 18.04. Newer releases of Ubuntu use the package `libssl1.1`. 18.04 has both packages.

Answer (score 11):

The results of `rmadison libssl1.0.0` show that the libssl1.0.0 package was dropped from the default Ubuntu repositories after Ubuntu 18.04.

```
$ rmadison libssl1.0.0
 libssl1.0.0 | 1.0.1-4ubuntu3     | precise          | amd64, armel, armhf, i386, powerpc
 libssl1.0.0 | 1.0.1-4ubuntu5.39  | precise-security | amd64, armel, armhf, i386, powerpc
 libssl1.0.0 | 1.0.1-4ubuntu5.39  | precise-updates  | amd64, armel, armhf, i386, powerpc
 libssl1.0.0 | 1.0.1f-1ubuntu2    | trusty           | amd64, arm64, armhf, i386, powerpc, ppc64el
 libssl1.0.0 | 1.0.1f-1ubuntu2.27 | trusty-security  | amd64, arm64, armhf, i386, powerpc, ppc64el
 libssl1.0.0 | 1.0.1f-1ubuntu2.27 | trusty-updates   | amd64, arm64, armhf, i386, powerpc, ppc64el
 libssl1.0.0 | 1.0.2g-1ubuntu4    | xenial           | amd64, arm64, armhf, i386, powerpc, ppc64el, s390x
 libssl1.0.0 | 1.0.2g-1ubuntu4.15 | xenial-security  | amd64, arm64, armhf, i386, powerpc, ppc64el, s390x
 libssl1.0.0 | 1.0.2g-1ubuntu4.15 | xenial-updates   | amd64, arm64, armhf, i386, powerpc, ppc64el, s390x
 libssl1.0.0 | 1.0.2n-1ubuntu5    | bionic           | amd64, arm64, armhf, i386, ppc64el, s390x
 libssl1.0.0 | 1.0.2n-1ubuntu5.3  | bionic-security  | amd64, arm64, armhf, i386, ppc64el, s390x
 libssl1.0.0 | 1.0.2n-1ubuntu5.3  | bionic-updates   | amd64, arm64, armhf, i386, ppc64el, s390x
```

The results of `apt search libssl` show that the libssl package has been upgraded to libssl1.1 in Ubuntu 19.04-20.04. To install it open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt install libssl1.1
```

libssl has been upgraded to libssl3 in Ubuntu 22.04-22.10.

Comment: Or similarly use `libssl1.0` which today leads to `libssl1.0.2`

Comment: Seems running `sudo apt-get install libssl1.0` does nothing. In my case, it says *0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.*

Answer (score 4):

If you need libssl1.0.0 on anything after Debian 8 (Jessie), you'll need to update your apt sources before apt installing.

Adding the following lines to my dockerfile worked:

```
RUN echo "deb http://security.debian.org/debian-security jessie/updates main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list
RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
    libssl1.0.0
```

Comment: This is askUBUNTU.com

Adding debian sources to a Ubuntu system is a very terrible idea.

Answer (score 3):

Add `http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-security` to the `sources.list` file:

```
sudo -i
echo "deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-security main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list
sudo apt update && apt-cache policy libssl1.0.0
```

Comment: Didn't work for me. I had to run apt update for this to work.
`sudo apt update && apt-cache policy libssl1.0.0`

Comment: Also, there is a missing `deb` before the http URL

Comment: @Rady ah oops, nice catch

Answer (score 3):

```
sudo -i
wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/o/openssl/libssl1.1_1.1.1f-1ubuntu2_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i libssl1.1_1.1.1f-1ubuntu2_amd64.deb
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to understand **why** your package manager is trying to install libssl1.0.0.  `aptitude why libssl1.0.0` will tell you.