# Have installed libssl1.0.0 but still getting the error, "libssl.so.1.0.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory"

Tags: package-management, ssl, r, rstudio

I installed libssl [1] and it seems to be done correctly but I still get thie following error when trying to open a dependent program (RStudio).

[1] [E: Package 'libssl1.0.0' has no installation candidate](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1173587/e-package-libssl1-0-0-has-no-installation-candidate)

Comment: Which commands did you use, exactly? How did you install RStudio?

Comment: This commonly occurs when folks use Ubuntu 20.04 instead of 18.04. libssl1.0.0 was dropped from Ubuntu after 18.04, superseded by libssl1.0.1. (The packages have different *names*). One simple answer is to use Ubuntu 18.04, which is fully supported until 2023, until RStudio catches up.

Comment: Thank you for the 2 above comments! (1) I downloaded the .deb from the rstudio site and used the package installer.  (2) So I need to install ubuntu 18.04, that is the only way?

Comment: No, that's just the easiest and safest workaround for new users...the folks who would ask this kind of question. If you are skilled, there are several other ways to use that obsolete package that might work, but also might break your system or leave your system vulnerable. We have not tested those. Fundamentally, this is an RStudio problem (not an Ubuntu problem) and they must fix it for Ubuntu 20.04 and newer releases.